# Batch rename files based on a common pattern

Tags: bash, rename

I have many files and all of them have the word `text` in them.

like `test text22 test.mp3`

"test" can include all kinds of characters -> `-/()(&%0-9...`

Now I want to rename every file so that a underscore is added before every "text" like `test_test22 test.mp4`.  Is there a straight forward way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Perl‘s standalone rename command:

```
rename -n 's/ (text[0-9]{1,2})/_$1/' *text*
```

If everything looks okay, remove option `-n`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it which illustrates the (often very useful) use of regular expression matching in Bash.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *
do
  if [[ $file =~ (.*)text(.*) ]] ; then
    mv "$file" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}text_${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
  fi
done
```

This would be especially useful if you want to do something other than just rename the files.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't want to *add* the underscore but *replace leading space with* it like in your example (but then again it had mp3 -> mp4 so just making sure):

```
$ ls
test text22 test.mp3
text22 test.mp3
$ for f in *text*; do "echo ${f/ text/_text}" ; done
test_text22 test.mp3
text22 test.mp3
```

To `mv` replace the echo with `mv "$f" "${f/ text/_text}"`